# BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range [tried cast function]

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively.

There is only one table as the below

`{"headers": {"Logs": ["Id", "Num"]}, "rows": {"Logs": [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 2], [7, 2]]}}`

```
select distinct num as ConsecutiveNums
from
(
    select num, (id - ranks) as rnk
    from
    (select cast(id as signed) as id, num,
            row_number() over (partition by num order by cast(id as signed)) as ranks
        from logs
    ) t
) tt

group by num,
    rnk
having count(*) > 2
```

I keep getting the unsigned error. I tried cast(id as signed). for some reasons, it is not working. any idea how to get around this error?

Error Details

```
BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`t`.`id` - `t`.`ranks`)'
```

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table logs;` and `select version();`

Comment: because unsigned is bigger than signed (has bigger maximum), so you are getting this error BECAUSE of casting ...

Comment: Try `select num, IF(id > ranks, id - ranks, 0) as rnk`

Comment: @ExploitFate  thank you so much! this works. is it due to the fact that mysql thinks that id<ranks happens?  my test case is "Logs": [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 2], [7, 2]].  it is in sequence. so I wonder why mysql finds id< ranks will happen

Comment: Maybe it's just validation to prevent type overflow